# Mejorar el rendimiento al obtener varios registros Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero saber cual es la mejor forma de obtener varios registros de una base mysql, Dejo una ejemplo sencillo de mi situación. Tengo un método estático que consulta una base de datos y convierte el resultado en un objeto que tengo definido.

```
class Persona {

    public $id;
    public $nombre;

    function __construct($id,$name){
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->nombre = $name;

    }

    public static function getPersona($personid){
        $db = new ConnectionDB();
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Persona WHERE id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('i',$personid);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id,$name);
        $stmt->fetch();
        return new Persona($id,$name);
    }

}
```

¿Que opción tendría mejor rendimiento?.

1. Opción 1: Crear un método que reciba varios id y los consulte uno por uno utilizando el método anterior

   ```
   public static function getPersonas($ids){
       $personas = array();
       foreach($ids as $id){
           $personas[] = new getPersona($id);
       }
       return $personas;
   }
   ```
2. Opción 2: Crear un método que utilice IN en la consulta.

   ```
   public static function getPersonas($ids){
       $db = new ConnectionDB();
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM personas WHERE id IN (" . implode(',',$ids) .")";
       $persons = array();
       if($result = $db->query($sql)){
           while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
               $persons[] = $row;
           }
       }
       $oPersons = array();
       foreach($persons as $p){
           $oPersons[] = new Persona($p['id'],$p['name']);
       }
       return $oPersons;
   }
   ```

Comment: La primera esta mal por que llamas el método varias veces y creas muchas conexiones, cuando podrias pasarle como parametro la conexion y asi hacer varias consultas (statements) con una Sola conexión abierta. Si corriges eso, las 2 tienen un rendimiento similiar (opcion 1 y 2). Aunque optaria obviamente por la opcion 2 que hace una unica consulta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las conexiones a la base son muy costosas en cuestión de tiempo, por lo que SIEMPRE lleva menos tiempo una única consulta que devuelva varios resultados (y puede ser considerablemente menos cuando la cantidad a recuperar es mucha).

Sin embargo, también se suele poner en la balanza otros atributos de calidad del software, como la mantenibilidad. En este caso, estaría bueno no duplicar los puntos desde donde se crea una persona desde la base de datos, ya que si luego es necesario agregar un nuevo atributo, hay 2 lugares para modificar.

Normalmente [no es una buena práctica hacer optimizaciones prematuras](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizaci%C3%B3n_prematura), ya que uno no sabe a priori dónde se encontrarán los cuellos de botella en un sistema. Luego, de haber problemas de performance, se toman mediciones y se arregla lo que corresponde.

En este caso, por ejemplo, si cuando se van a buscar las personas estamos hablando de 2, 3 o 20, en ese caso no tendría un impacto significativo y sería mucho peor, a mi criterio, la duplicación de la lógica de creación de personas.

Comment: Me parece que en el segundo caso no hay duplicación, porque getPersonas implicaría que ya no se declara getPersona.

Comment: Entiendo, pero eso implica que elimina la primer función, no? No lo había interpretado así. Lo único que eso obliga a que si lo más común es ir a buscar a una única persona, siempre tratar con un array, lo que puede requerir alguna complejidad adicional. Por supuesto que es salvable, y también lo es manteniendo ambas funciones. Sólo fue una aclaración y un ejemplo de los precios que puede tener una optimización y qué cosas poner en la balanza. La decisión última, siempre depende del caso.

Comment: Sí, tu respuesta es esencialmente correcta sin importar los supuestos que hayas hecho, por eso te voté.

Comment: Gracias @amenadiel!